# Periodicity of $f$ such that $ f(x+2)=f(x-1)f(x+5)$

Tags: real-analysis, periodic-functions

Let $f$ be a real valued function defined from :$\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R^*}$ such that

$$ f(x+2)=f(x-1)f(x+5).$$

How do i show that $f$ is peridoic ?

**Note:** I have tried to show that for every real number $x$ that $f(x+2)=f(x)$ but I can't since I ignored the form of the function

Answer (score 5):

Hint:   $f(x)=f(x-3)f(x+3)=f(x-6)f(x)f(x+3) \implies f(x-6)f(x+3)=1\,$.

Comment: I don't understand well this answer, it's seems to me missing some detaill and far for the form of my title identity, sorry

Comment: @JackWonder The first equality is the same as yours with $x+2 \mapsto x\,$, which also means $\,x-1 \mapsto x-3\,$ and $\,x+5 \mapsto x+3\,$. The next equality is reusing the first one for $f(x-3)$.